# Plotting quadratic curves with poisson glm with interactions in categorical/numeric variables

Tags: r, plot, glm, poisson, quadratic-curve

I want to know if it's possible to plot quadratic curves with Poisson glm with interactions in categorical/numeric variables. In my case:

```
##Data set artificial
set.seed(20)
d <- data.frame(
  behv = c(rpois(100,10),rpois(100,100)),
  mating=sort(rep(c("T1","T2"), 200)),
  condition = scale(rnorm(200,5))
) 

#Condition quadratic
d$condition2<-(d$condition)^2

#Binomial GLM ajusted
md<-glm(behv ~ mating + condition + condition2, data=d, family=poisson)
summary(md)
```

In a situation where mating, condition and condition2 are significant in the model, I make:

```
#Create x's vaiues
x<-d$condition## 
x2<-(d$condition)^2 

# T1 estimation
y1<-exp(md$coefficients[1]+md$coefficients[3]*x+md$coefficients[4]*x2)
#
# T2 estimation
y2<-exp(md$coefficients[1]+md$coefficients[2]+md$coefficients[3]*x+md$coefficients[4]*x2)
#
#
#Separete data set
d_T1<-d[d[,2]!="T2",] 
d_T2<-d[d[,2]!="T1",] 

#Plot
plot(d_T1$condition,d_T1$behv,main="", xlab="condition", ylab="behv", 
xlim=c(-4,3), ylim=c(0,200), col= "black")
points(d_T2$condition,d_T2$behv, col="gray")
lines(x,y1,col="black")
lines(x,y2,col="grey")
#
```

Doesn't work and I don't have my desirable curves. I'd like a curve for T1 and other for T2 in mating variable. There are any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, we use the `poly` function to generate a quadratic model without needing to create an extra column in the data frame. In addition, we create a prediction data frame to generate model predictions across the range of `condition` values and for each level of `mating`. The `predict` function with `type="response"` generates predictions on the scale of the outcome, rather than on the linear predictor scale, which is the default. Also, we change `200` to `100` in creating the data for `mating` in order to avoid having the exact same outcome data for each level of `mating`.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Fake data
set.seed(20)
d <- data.frame(
  behv = c(rpois(100,10),rpois(100,100)),
  mating=sort(rep(c("T1","T2"), 100)),   # Changed from 200 to 100
  condition = scale(rnorm(200,5))
)

# Model with quadratic condition
md <- glm(behv ~ mating + poly(condition, 2, raw=TRUE), data=d, family=poisson)
#summary(md)

# Get predictions at range of condition values
pred.data = data.frame(condition = rep(seq(min(d$condition), max(d$condition), length=50), 2),
                       mating = rep(c("T1","T2"), each=50))
pred.data$behv = predict(md, newdata=pred.data, type="response")
```

Now plot with ggplot2 and with base R:

```
ggplot(d, aes(condition, behv, colour=mating)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pred.data)
```

[image]

```
plot(NULL, xlim=range(d$condition), ylim=range(d$behv),
     xlab="Condition", ylab="behv")
with(subset(d, mating=="T1"), points(condition, behv, col="red"))
with(subset(d, mating=="T2"), points(condition, behv, col="blue"))
with(subset(pred.data, mating=="T1"), lines(condition, behv, col="red"))
with(subset(pred.data, mating=="T2"), lines(condition, behv, col="blue"))
legend(-3, 70, title="Mating", legend=c("T1","T2"), pch=1, col=c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]